# Fetch more function is undefined for useLazyQuery react-apollo hook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I use react-apollo useLazyQuery hook. My goal to use it in fetch more button click. However, when I try to use it the fetchMore function is undefined.

Here the call to it:

```
const [getMyData,{ loading, data, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(
    myQuery,
    {
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      variables: {}
})
```

Even if I run lazy on component ready, fetchMoreStill undefined.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    getMyData()
  },[])
```

The question is why it is undefined?

> "apollo-client": "^2.6.4", "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",

Comment: testing this theory could be faster than writting this question

Comment: @xadm tested, updated

Comment: show how tested

Comment: this is only half of this test :D

Comment: ... and `getMyPledges` != `getMyData`

Comment: My fault, upadted

Comment: `if(data) console.log('fetchMore ', fetchMore);` ... if run on mount/ready then no lazy needed ;)

Comment: But, I do not want to run it on mount/ready, I want to run it on my need

Comment: you claimed it's still undefined ... just run conditionally - if data run fetchMore, getXXXdata if 1st time

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `loadItem` first. My case also loads on demand because I'm using SSR.

Here is my work around, check the `fetchMore` is undefined to make the decision

[image]

```
function NewItemListingPagination({
  initialItems,
  initialPage,
  initialLimit,
  initialTotal,
  className
}: ComponentPropTypes) {
  const { t } = useTranslation(['homepage', 'common'])
  const page = useRef<number>(initialPage)
  const [loadItem, { loading, data, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(FEED_NEW_ITEM)

  async function loadMore(): Promise<void> {
    const newPage = page.current + 1
    const offset = (newPage - 1) * initialLimit
    page.current = newPage

    if (!fetchMore) {
      loadItem({
        variables: {
          limit: 12,
          offset
        }
      })
    } else {
      fetchMore({
        query: FEED_NEW_ITEM,
        variables: {
          limit: 12,
          offset
        },
        updateQuery: (previousResult, {fetchMoreResult}) => {
          console.log('dddd', previousResult, fetchMoreResult)
          return previousResult
        }
      })
    }
  }

  const items = !data ? initialItems : initialItems.concat(data.feed.items)

  return <div></div>
```

NOTE: this code may not optimized, I just want to show the flow of fetchMore.

Answer (score -2):

I am also new to react but as far as I know you have to use refetch and than give it a name like this:

```
const [getMyData,{ loading, data, refetch: fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery...
```

you can do the same thing with data and loading.

```
const [getMyData,{ loading: myLoading, data: myData, refetch: fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery...
```

Comment: nope, it's just renaming ... usable when many hooks used within one component

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. I thought you you had to use the keywords to rename it. Should I just delete my answer then? I am new to this.